# 400 Bad Request when posting JSON Array to a Spring controller

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, http-post

I have been successful in sending a simple JSON object over to a spring framework Controller

```
curl -v -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -d '{"lastName":"Smith","firstName":"John"}' http://localhost:8080/WebServices02/aura/testJsonArray
```

**However**, when I send over a JSON  object with an embedded array

```
curl -v -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -d '{"lastName":"Smith","pals":[{"name":"Billy"}],"firstName":"John"}' http://localhost:8080/WebServices02/aura/testJsonArray
```

I get the error 400 'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().'

My controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/aura")
public class AuraController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/testJsonArray", method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public void testJsonArray(@RequestBody  Aura aura){
    System.err.println("Called testJsonArray(): " + "Aura is " + aura.toString());
}
```

}

My Aura class is defined as

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Aura implements Serializable {

public class Pal{
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}


private String firstName;

private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

private List<Pal> pals;

public String toString(){
    return new JSONObject(this).toString();

}

public List<Pal> getPals() {
    return pals;
}

public void setPals(List<Pal> pals) {
    this.pals = pals;
}
```

}

My bean (under mvc:message-converters) is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

If someone can help me on this... thanks

Comment: Duh... silly mistake. Pal should not be an inner class. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

> You have to include  Jackson JSON Mapper dependency for jackson-core-asl and jackson-mapper-asl in your project.
>
> This is necessary for mapping json with java pojo class fields.

Comment: (I figured this out just after posting), the reason (for the embedded array not working while a simple JSON array did) was Pal being an inner class. Once I made it a separate class it all worked.... thanks for trying to help